# C Program to find if two words are anagrams (my code inside)

Tags: c, arrays, function

The program prompts the user to type two words stored in two different arrays.
If the words are anagram it would print "Anagram", if not it'd print "Not Anagram". I made an array for all the alphabet letters, letter 'a' is stored as {1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...} filling in he whole array of letters.

Then I compared both arrays, to determine if they are the same word I substracted each letter and if they are 0 (cancel out each other) they are Anagrams.
Here's my code so far, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I'm pretty sure there's something wrong in the Boolean function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void read_word(int counts[26])
{
    int i;
    char ch;

    printf("Enter a word: ");
    for(i=0;(ch=getchar()) != '\n' && i<30; i++)
        counts[toupper(ch)-'A']++;
}

bool equal_array(int counts1[26],int counts2[26])
{
    int i;
    bool is_anagram=false;   
    for(i=0; i<30; i++)
    {
        counts1[i]= counts1[i] - counts2[i];
        if(counts1[i] == 0)
            {
              is_anagram=true;
            }
        else
        {
            is_anagram=false;
            break;
        }

    }
   return is_anagram;
}

int main()
{

    int first_word[26]={0};
    int second_word[26]={0};


    read_word(first_word);

    read_word(second_word);


     if( equal_array(first_word,second_word) == true)
        printf("Anagram");
    else
        printf("Not Anagram");

    return 0;
}
```

I'd appreciate any help I could get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bool equal_array(int counts1[26],int counts2[26])
...
for(i=0; i<30; i++)
```

means that you will end up comparing the 27th through 30th elements of arrays with only 26 elements. That's (1) undefined behaviour, (2) an obvious bug, and (3) likely to produce the wrong result if it doesn't crash and burn.

---

I don't see why you have a 30-character limit in your read loop either. You're not storing the words anywhere, so there's no reason to arbitrarily limit their lengths. On the other hand, you don't check that the letters are actually in the range `A`..`Z`, so if the user enters a non-alphabetic character, your function will modify some random byte outside the range of the count array, leading to undefined behaviour, as above.

---

Finally, it would be a little shorter to write:

```
bool equal_array(int counts1[26],int counts2[26]) {
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<26; i++) {
        if(counts1[i] != counts2[i]) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Some people don't like returns in the middle of loops like that, so if your professor is one of those people I suppose you will need the boolean variable. But personally I find the version above easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool equal_array(int counts1[26],int counts2[26])
{
    int i;
    bool is_anagram=true;   
    for(i=0; i<26; i++)//30 : occures out of bounds
    {
        if(counts1[i] != counts2[i] )
        {
            is_anagram=false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return is_anagram;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string firstWord = String.Empty;
        string secondWord = String.Empty;
        Console.WriteLine("Check if two strings are anagrams");
        Console.WriteLine("Enter First String");
        firstWord = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Second String");
        secondWord = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Ara Anagram: " + AreAnagrams(firstWord.ToLower(), secondWord.ToLower()).ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static bool AreAnagrams(string firstWord, string secondWord)
    {
        if (firstWord.Length == 0 || firstWord.Length != secondWord.Length)
            return false;

        string letters = new String(firstWord.Distinct().ToArray());

        foreach (char letter in letters)
        {
            char lowerLetter = Char.ToLower(letter);
            if (firstWord.Count(c => c == lowerLetter) != secondWord.Count(c => c == lowerLetter)) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```